# Behaviour of TextureView#onSurfaceTextureDestroyed

Tags: android

The behaviour of `onSurfaceTextureDestroyed` function in the `TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener` interface is very inconsistent among different android version.

The normal behaviour is that when used with a `TextureView` in an `Activity`, the `TextureView` should be destroyed when we go to an another `Activity` from there and we should get the `onSurfaceTextureDestroyed` callback.  This works consistently in some OS versions but it doesnt work in Android 7.1.1 or Android 4.2 or Android 4.1. I mean i dont get the `onSurfaceTextureDestroyed` callback when i go to another `Activity` from the current `Activity`(where `TextureView` is present) on these OS versions and the `TextureView` is not destroyed in this case.

When i go to another `Activity` from current `Activity`, then i also get the `onPause()` and `onStop()` callbacks of the previous `Activity`.

Why is this behaviour so inconsistent?

The relevant code is this.

```
textureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(new TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
                Log.d(TAG,"AVAILABLE");
            }

            @Override
            public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {

            }

            @Override
            public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surface) {
                Log.d(TAG,"DESTROYED");
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surface) {

            }
        });
```